# Does Puppet module use internet to install sotware?

Tags: puppet

I am planing to use [msoffice](https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/msoffice/readme) module to install MS Office but the machine I am planning it to be installed on, doesn't have internet connection. Does the module download the installer from a website which in turn requires an active internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the module download the installer from a website which in turn requires an active internet connection?

Examining [the module source](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-msoffice) would reveal that no, it does not.  It relies on an image of the installation media for each product to be accessible via the target node's filesystem, and you would have to arrange for that separately. With respect to that, each of the user-facing classes and defined types provided by the module does have a parameter [`deployment_root`](https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/msoffice/readme#deployment_root), defined as:

> The network location where the office installation media is stored

That turns out to be used as a path prefix, apparently with the idea that the installation media might be on an accessible network share (not the Internet), as opposed to being on a local disk.  I imagine that situation is fairly common for users of the module.

Thus, having an Internet connection is not directly relevant to this module, but having access to installation media is another matter entirely.